# Getting gputools and gmatrix in R to run smoothly on Linux

Tags: r, linux, gpu, opensuse

I am having trouble getting R to recognize gmatrix for R, running through Rstudio. My details are below.

- Things that are accomplished and DONE:

  - install of openSuse Tumbleweed x86_64
  - install of NVIDIA graphics driver 361.42
  - install of CUDA 7.5 & symbolic link for /usr/local/cuda

    - set LD_LIBRARY_PATH & PATH
  - R 3.2.5
  - RStudio 0.98.501-1.62
  - patched /usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h, line: 115 by increasing the "4"'s to "5"'s (this pertains to the gcc compiler)
  - install package gputools
  - ~ partial install of package gmatrix

*I had to edit the host_config.h file because cuda is not supported for the gcc compiler that Tumbleweed ships with. I basically broke the evaluation that checks for version and set it to 5.9 instead of 4.9. Was this a supremely naive thing to do?

- Things not Done, help required:

-I wasn't able to install gmatrix properly. I got R to install by manually adding the LD & PATH directories using the Sys.setenv()

```
> Sys.setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"="/usr/lib64/R/lib:/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64")

> Sys.setenv("PATH"="/home/eamergent/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/usr/local/cuda/bin")
```

However, I am unable to load the gmatrix package, yet gputools works fine:

```
> library(gputools) "no issues"

> library(gmatrix)

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : unable to load shared object '/home/eamergent/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/3.2/gmatrix/libs/gmatrix.so':libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘gmatrix’
```

*The Error makes it seem that libcudart.so.7.5 is to blame
However,
/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.7.5 does in fact exist:

```
> eamergent@linux-pnx7: ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcuda

libcudadevrt.a       libcudart.so         libcudart.so.7.5     libcudart.so.7.5.18  libcudart_static.a
```

*I used tab to get a shorter list. there are many more in lib64

Any ideas on how to get R to recognize the already installed gmatrix package? Or how to properly reinstall without using the R environment path fix that I used above?

Comment: ***Please forgive my formatting. I have not posted to a forum in quite some time.

Comment: I believe in this case you could also set the `LD_RUN_PATH` environmental variable as well.  That should allow it to find the shared object.

Comment: My apologies, would i set this in the system's teminal or R's? And I assume it would be the path for the lib64 instead of the bin path.

Comment: I have checked the Rsession and found no LD_RUN_PATH, or RUN of any kind in the Sys.getenv().  I tried to set the RUN path to the lib64 in the system terminal with  <export LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LD_RUN_PATH> this attempt didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 where the system and R (Sys.setenv()) shared library paths were set properly, but R failed to load the CUDA shared library. What worked was to set the CUDA shared library path using ldconfig.

as root or prefix commands with sudo:

```
# echo "/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcuda" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/cuda.conf
# ldconfig
```

then

```
# R
> install.packages("gmatrix")
```

or if gmatrix is already installed

```
# R
> library(gmatrix)
> gtest()
```